# Solution space of homogenous system

Tags: linear-algebra

Find all $3 \times 3$ matrices for which the homogeneous system has a solution space as the line
$x = 2 t , y = t , z = 0$.
Write the row reduced augmented matrix from given
information. What is the rank in this case?

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A homogeneous linear equation is one of the form $A\mathbf x = \mathbf 0$, where $A$ is a matrix, $\mathbf x = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\ x_m\end{bmatrix}$, and $\mathbf 0 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$.

The solution space is the set of all $\mathbf x$'s that satisfy this equation.

So let's see if we can figure this one out.  Let's start with the reduced row echelon form.  We have
$$\begin{bmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\ 0 & a_{22} & a_{23} \\ 0 & 0 & a_{33}\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \iff \begin{cases} a_{11}x + a_{12}y + a_{13}z=0 \\ a_{22}y + a_{23}z=0 \\ a_{33}z=0 \end{cases}$$

The only possibilities for the diagonal elements are $0$ or $1$.  From this last equation, and your condition $z=0$, we can see that $a_{33}$ has to equal $1$ or else we'd have $0z=0$, in which case $z$ would be a "free variable".

Knowing $z=0$, we can reduce this $3$ equations I have above to these two: $\begin{cases} a_{11}x + a_{12}y = 0 \\ a_{22}y=0\end{cases}$.  Again $a_{22}$ has to be $1$ or $0$, so either $y=0$ or $y$ is a free variable.  Looking at your condition $y=t$, we can see that $y$ is a free variable, thus $a_{22}=0$.

Knowing this, let's look at the one equation we have left $a_{11}x+a_{12}y = a_{11}+a_{12}t=0\implies a_{11}x=-a_{12}t$.  Now let's use your last condition, $x=2t$.  Therefore we can see that $a_{11} = 1$ and $a_{12} = -2$.  Thus our matrix looks like
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -2 & a_{13} \\ 0 & 0 & a_{23} \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

Because in reduced row eschelon form, all of the elements *above a leading $1$* are $0$, we know that $a_{13}=a_{23}=0$ as well.

So our final RREF form matrix is $$R=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

The rank of this matrix is $2$ because there are both $2$ linearly independent rows of this matrix (the first and the third) and $2$ linearly independent columns of this matrix (the third and either the first OR the second).

Because the kernel of a matrix is preserved by elementary row operations, the set of all matrices which $A$ with the same kernel as this RREF matrix, will be those that can be obtained by elementary row operations from the matrix $R$.

Equivalently, it'll be the set of all matrices of the form $PR$, where [$P$ is any arbitary *invertible* matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1065619/can-we-specify-all-row-equivalent-matrices-of-a-given-matrix/1065648#1065648).

Thus all such matrices will be of the form $\begin{bmatrix} \mathbf c_1 & -2\mathbf c_1 & \mathbf c_3\end{bmatrix}$, where $\mathbf c_1$ and $\mathbf c_3$ are two linearly independent column vectors.