# Can we specify all row equivalent matrices of a given matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Say we have a RREF matrix like $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

From this matrix, is there some way of specifying ALL of the matrices which are row equivalent to this one?

Comment: @AhaanS.Rungta I've considered that row equivalent matrices can be obtained via $1$: switching rows, $2$: scaling a row, and $3$: adding a scalar multiple of a row to another row.  It seems like it should be $\begin{bmatrix} a & 0 & b & 0 \\ d & 0 & e & 0 \\ f & 0 & g & 0\end{bmatrix}$ where exactly $2$ of the rows are linearly independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing an elementary row operation on a matrix is equivalent to multiply the matrix (on the left) by a particular invertible matrix (usually called an elementary matrix). So the elimination on a matrix $A$ to a RREF matrix $U$ is the same as writing $FA=U$, where $F$ is the product of the elementary matrices used in the process.

Any invertible matrix can be expressed as the product of elementary matrices: just reduce the matrix to its RREF, which is the identity and apply the same as before.

Thus the matrices that are row equivalent to $U$ are all matrices of the form $XU$, with $X$ invertible. If $X=[x_1\ x_2\ x_3\ x_4]$ ($x_i$ is the $i$-th column of $X$) and we write your matrix $U=[e_1\ 0\ e_2\ 0]$, then
$$
XU=[Xe_1\ X0\ Xe_2\ X0]=[x_1\ 0\ x_2\ 0]
$$
Since $X$ is an arbitrary invertible matrix, its columns $x_1$ and $x_2$ are arbitrary *linearly independent* vectors.

Comment: OK.  That makes sense.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$

Has vectors $(x_1,0,0,0)$ and $(0,0,x_3,0)$, which lets us have any linear combination of $(\alpha x_1,0,\beta x_3,0)$ with arbitrary $\alpha,\beta$.

Comment: So the set of all matrices row equivalent to mine is $\begin{bmatrix} a & 0 & b & 0 \\ d & 0 & e & 0 \\ f & 0 & g & 0\end{bmatrix}$, for $a,b,c,d,e,f,g \in \Bbb R$, where at least $2$ of the rows are linearly independent?

Comment: @user200794 Not so, think about how they can alter eachother.

Comment: @user200794 Can you clarify your 'where at least $2$ of the rows are linearly independent'?

Comment: It's probably "where exactly $2$ of the rows are linearly independent".  Which means that $a_1r_1 + a_2r_2 + a_3r_3 = 0$ has a nontrivial solution, but at least one of the equations $a_ir_i + a_jr_j=0$, where $r_i$ is a row vector, $a_i$ is a scalar, and $i\ne j$, does not have any solutions but the trivial solution.